# How to fix catkin Depends error..? ROS2 galactic

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Console:

```
sx-VirtualBox:~/catkin_ws/src$ catkin_make
Command 'catkin_make' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install catkin

sx-VirtualBox:~/catkin_ws/src$ sudo apt install catkin
[sudo] password for kris-x: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 catkin : Depends: python3-catkin-pkg (>= 0.4.14-2) but it is not going to be installed
**E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.**
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384666/how-to-fix-catkin-depends-error..?-ros2-galactic/) by [krishan.iot.w](https://answers.ros.org/users/81670/krishan.iot.w/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-08-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You cannot use Catkin with ROS 2.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [krishan.iot.w](https://answers.ros.org/users/81670/krishan.iot.w/) on 2021-08-19**:
Thank you gvdhoom for your answer. For me it is very useful.. I could have worked harder for it. If not..I am trying to make a URDF from fusion 360 and run it. I did not get the exact tutorial for that. **Can I have a guide for that?**

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-08-19**:
I would not be able to refer you to one, as I'm not aware of one.